Is the music played for Admiral Yamamoto’s arrival scene the Japanese national anthem or something else?
In the opening scene of Tora! Tora! Tora! (1970), where Admiral Yamamoto comes onto the flagship to take command, what exactly is the tune being played as he walks along the red carpet?
I assumed at first that it must be the Japanese national anthem, but I've heard that online, and the tunes are alike but not identical.
Does anyone know?

Voting to leave open. I believe there is no community consensus to ban all questions that involve identifying something about a movie.

It is "Umi Yukaba" (海行かば), a piece of music that was composed in 1937 by  Kiyoshi Nobutoki, based upon an 8th Century poem. Popular with the military, especially the Navy, you can see why it would have been used to play for Yamamoto's arrival and would have been appreciated. Interestingly, it is so popular that it is regarded as Japan's second National anthem:
https://skdesu.com/en/kimigayo-national-anthem-japanese/

UMIYUKABA - SECOND NATIONAL ANTHEM
After Japan surrendered in 1945, “Umi Yukaba” and other gunka (military music) were banned.
However, the ban by the Occupying Nation (USA) was lifted and the song is now considered acceptable enough to be played publicly by the Japan Maritime Self-Defense Force, considered the second National Anthem...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umi_Yukaba
from wiki:

"Umi Yukaba" (海行かば) is a Japanese song whose lyrics are based on a chōka poem by Ōtomo no Yakamochi in the Man'yōshū (poem 4094), an eighth century anthology of Japanese poetry, set to music by Kiyoshi Nobutoki.


"Umi Yukaba" later became popular among the military, especially with the Imperial Japanese Navy. As set to music in 1937 by Kiyoshi Nobutoki (信時 潔, Nobutoki Kiyoshi) it became popular during and also after World War II.
"Umi Yukaba" is featured in the 1970 film, Tora! Tora! Tora!.










https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066473/soundtrack/

Umi Yukaba
Music by Kiyoshi Nobutoki
Played by Japanese band on IJN warship

(Region restricted) clip on YT:




Tora! Tora! Tora! : Yamamoto Isoroku takes office as new commander of the Combined Fleet


Many thanks. By whatever name it is a very nice tune,.  If only Japanese behaviour had been half as nice as their music, we'd all have been spared a lot of misery. Regrettably though I can't say the same for the words, which are more apt for a funeral march than a patriotic air. It would be like singing "Hanging on the old barbed wire" in honour of Field Marshall Haig.
